# University Calculus Problem

Tags: calculus

this was given as a practice problem and it has got me stumped for a while, any help would be great!

Say you get on the train from Toronto on a Tuesday at 12:00 am and arrive in Saskatoon
exactly 24 hours later on Wednesday at 12:00 am. Once it reaches Saskatoon, the train reverses and immediately starts traveling along the exact same route, and you start going back to Toronto. You arrive back in Toronto exactly 24 hours later on Thursday at 12:00am . Prove you were at some point on the route between Toronto and Saskatoon at exactly the same time on both Wednesday and Thursday.

Comment: Which part are you stumped on?

Comment: I guess on how to go about proving it

Comment: Informal proof. Suppose that a train leaves Toronto towards Saskatoon on Wednesday at $12:00$. The two trains will meet.

Comment: I have tried using the intermediate value theorem before and i just cant seem to figure it out

Comment: Let $f(t)$ be the distance from Toronto on the first trip at time $t$, measured with $t=0$ at the beginning of the trip. Let $g(t)$ be the distance from Toronto on the second trip at time $t$, where $t=0$ at the beginning of the trip. Let $h(t)=f(t)-g(t)$. Note that $h(0)$ is negative at $t=0$ and positive at $t=24$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I assume that you mean by saying "Note that h(0) is negative at t=0 and positive at t=24" that there is a real root, if not can you explain why you stated that. Also if does mean that there is a real root why that would help me prove that I was at some point on the route between Toronto and Saskatoon at exactly the same time on both Wednesday and Thurday.

Comment: If $h(c)=0$, then we are the same distance from Toronto at the same clock time $c$ on both trips, i.e. we are at the same place.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  
do you mean h(t)? or is h(c) something different?

Comment: $h(t)$ is the function for general time $t$. The number $c$ is a time $c$ when $h(c)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You're being asked to prove something happened between Toronto and Saskatoon. In other words, you're being asked to prove something about an *intermediate* location. Do you know any theorems about *intermediate values*?

---

Since in the comments, you mention you're not sure how to apply the intermediate value theorem, here's an explanation. Put clock time on the $x$-axis and distance on the $y$-axis. Your train leaves Toronto at $12:00$ am, i.e., at time $0$, and arrives in Saskatoon $24$ hours later, at time $24$.

We're interested in whether the two trains were ever in the same place at the same clock time, so as Andre Nicolas suggests, let's pretend the trains were traveling the same day. Then being in the same place at the same clock time will mean being in the same place at the same time. So the Saskatoon-to-Toronto train will leave Saskatoon at time $0$ and arrive in Toronto at time $24$.

If you draw a graph, you should get two diagonal lines that form an $X$. Our job is to prove that they actually do form an $X$. To do this, we'll apply the intermediate value theorem.

Let $h(t)$ be the distance from the Toronto-to-Saskatoon train to the Saskatoon-to-Toronto train at time $t$. It's positive before the trains cross and negative after they cross. This is where the intermediate value theorem comes in, and I'll let you have the *denouement*: Since $h(0) > 0$ and $h(24)<0$, how can you apply the intermediate value theorem to show the existence of a time $t$ such that $h(t) = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try applying the [intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, imagine the route between the cities is a line of length $D$. Let $x_1(t)$ be your position on that line, as a function of time, on the first trip and let $d_2(t)$ be the same for the second trip. Then $d_1(0)=0$ and $d_1(24{\rm h})=D$ while $d_2(0)=D$ and $d_2(24{\rm h})=0$.

Now, $f(t)=d_1(t)-d_2(t)$ has $f(0)=-D$ and $f(24{\rm h})=D$ and is, assumedly, continuous. Apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: I read your answer and it makes sense but I'm not sure where to go from where you left off.